# I just fried my Arduino on a breadboard. Can I still use the breadboard?

Tags: arduino-nano

So, I just fried my arduino nano on a breadboard. Can I still use the breadboard and usb cable?

Comment: If the breadboard failed from over current, there's a good chance you will see visible heat damage to the encapsulating plastic.

Comment: "Is this broken."
Well, does it still work?

It's hard for us to tell if something is working or not, we can't see the situation. If you want a definitive answer, you should try it out.

If plugging in the USB cable doesn't pop-up a "over current" message on your PC, you can safely plug it into a new Arduino.
If you can program the Arduino, it's still working.

For the breadboard, you'll have to check if there are no "shorts" where they shouldn't be.

Comment: Did you friend it or fry it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the circumstances around its demise. If it went out in smoke and flames, maybe not. Assuming the chip quietly overheated and died, the breadboard and the cable are almost certainly ok. Either of them will stand more abuse than the chip will. What was the cause of failure?

Comment: I think I short circuited it. The nano went up in smoke and I quickly turned off the power. I'm new to arduinos, so I was also wondering if 2$ breadboards from online will work just as well? Thank you :)

Comment: @Ethan get a continuity tester and test the pins that you use that burnt out the Arduino. If you are certain some don't work, then yea get a new breadboard or live without using some of the breadboard pins.

Comment: The differences I've found between breadboards is the quality of the internal connector system. If the maker didn't hold the tolerances closely enough, it can be difficult to push wires into them the first few times (and conversely, I suppose - some could be too loose). I had one that wasn't quite flat on the bottom. These are *really* simple devices; it's hard to screw them up, even though a few knock-off makers try. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can test the breadboard if you have a multimeter. Even if you don't, you can place an LED, a resistor and a power source across the suspect portions of the breadboard. If you locate a trace or two that appear unreliable, you should be able to mark them appropriately and continue to use the board.

Comment: What about the usb cable?

Comment: If you're asking about the health of the USB cable, you can also test it with a multimeter or simply by connecting to your computer something that uses USB. The amount of current that passed into your breadboard to destroy the chip is likely of short enough duration to not have damaged the USB cable. I expect also that the breadboard is undamaged.